# Kernel mode and User mode Drivers

Tags: windows, visual-studio, drivers, kernel-mode, usermode

I am a beginner in driver development. I want to know where exactly a **kernel mode driver and a user mode driver** resides in the main memory (Portion of main memory). And how to specify a driver as kernel mode driver or user mode driver while creating a driver project in **visual studio**

Answer (score 0):

A kernel driver may exist in non-paged memory, that's the main difference.

A user-mode driver is just a COM DLL, so you just specify it as such.